# How to make Sharepoint calendar reflect individual user timezone?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Our timezone by default is Pacific but we have users in Central time and their Sharepoint calendars aren't reflecting their timezone entered on the calendar. I did a test calendar event where I put 3pm-4pm I would've imagined on their end it would be viewed as 4-5pm? That isn't the case though. I just want to make sure that if I set something on the calendar with an alert they they will get it based on their timezone.   As you can see below, I changed the individual who is in Central time to their correct time zone so it isn't using our region default.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported in SharePoint calendar list. I would suggest you use Outlook calendar for this situation.

See a UserVoice post here: [SharePoint Calendar views adjust for local time zone.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/8230407-sharepoint-calendar-views-adjust-for-local-time-zo)

Also a similar post: [Organization with more than 1 time zone and SharePoint calendars.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/organization-with-more-than-1-time-zone-and-sharepoint-calendars/m-p/201955)